# Regex expression matching names in #{} for template usage

Tags: javascript, regex, templates, prototype

I'm creating a template script of sorts so I can drop in a variable name inside #{} and have that variable's contents render out to the page. This is for prototyping purposes.

An example of this is having a variable named "fullname", which contains the text "John Doe", if I write html like this:

```
<body>
    <p>Hello, #{fullname}! How are you doing?</p>
</body>
```

It will output:

```
<body>
    <p>Hello, John Doe! How are you doing?</p>
</body>
```

I'm using the regex expression equivalent of /#\{fullname\}/g which is working pretty well for me, compiling it with:

```
 new RegExp('#\{' + varName + '\}','g');
```

However, I have found if I put plain numbers in as the variable name the expression gives unexpected results (these are not javascript variables, so '1' is a valid name. The variable names themselves are stored in an xml). If the variable is named '1' , the regex expression replaces all the pounds on the page.

So /#\{1\}/g replaces all # symbols in the document. If I put in 0 instead, it gets really funky and replaces almost everything. 2 does nothing. I would like to know what is happening?

**EDIT** - 
I should note that writing out

```
/#\{1\}/g
```

does not cause an issue, but it's when I use

```
new RegExp('#\{1\}','g')
```

this issue occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new RexExp` object needs double escaping so use:

```
new RegExp('#\\{' + varName + '\\}', 'g');
```

Otherwise regex engine is getting `#{1}` instead of `#\{1\}` hence each `#` is getting replaced.

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I forgot that \ is a special character inside a string as well...